# How can we migrate sequence in PostgreSQL to Mysql

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

All,

I am trying to migrate from PostgreSQL DB to MySql DB. I have used sequence in some table to get auto increment column other than the primary key. How to create auto increment column which is the primary key in Mysql DB.

I am listing an example table below in PostgreSQL.

```
CREATE TABLE bills
(
      id serial NOT NULL,
      billname character varying(255) NOT NULL,
      invoiceid character varying(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('bill_invoiceid_seq'::regclass),
      CONSTRAINT combine_campaigns_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

In the example, "id" is the primary key and invoice id is not a key but getting auto increment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent for a SERIAL column in mysql is AUTO_INCREMENT. Define your primary key as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table(
   id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   ...
)
```

or

```
 CREATE TABLE my_table(
   id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
   ...
   PRIMARY KEY(id)
)
```

Be aware that in mysql you can only have one AUTO_INCREMENT per table. Also worth mentioning is that you are moving from an RDBS that is rich in features and closer to standard compliance to one that has less features and less compliant.

Comment: thank you for your reply, but I need to get a way to use auto increment other than the primary key. I have modified question with an example.

Comment: Sorry that's not allowed by mysql. " you are moving from an RDBS that is rich in features and closer to standard compliance to one that has less features and less compliant."

Comment: There are certain work arounds which can work wtih different degrees of reliability. May I suggest that you mark this answer as correct and post a new question asking how to create a non primary key auto incrementing column in mysql. There are quite a few answers for that already.

Comment: my answer is the correct answer to your question. Because even after your edit it shows your postgrsql table having the serial column as primary key :-)

Comment: thank you for your reply, sorry, I have missed a word ("not") in question, that changed the meaning of the question completely. I have corrected now. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Would the person who gave the -vote care to explain what's wrong with this answer?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL **int auto_increment primary key** should be very similar to postgreSQL **serial** (which does not need to be a primary key)

If you want to reserve some used sequence, you can insert a value (eg 3000) into MySQL auto_increment field, after that any new record will increase from this value i.e. 3001 onwards:

[image]

Comment: thank you for your reply, sorry, I have missed a word ("not") in question, that changed the meaning of the question completely. I have corrected now. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Well, in MySQL only primary key has auto_increment